# numerical homotopy continuation method gets stuck on solving polynomial systems

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, homotopy-theory

I tried Bertini software to solve a polynomial system however it gets stuck at `Removing junk points from codimension 15: 44 endpoints to check`.

here is the input file

```
% TwistedCubic.input 

CONFIG
TrackType: 1; 
END; 

INPUT

variable_group sa,sb,sc,sd,se,sf,sg,sh,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce,cf,cg,ch;
function f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16;

f1 = -cb*sa - cc*sa - ce*sa - cg*sa - ch*sa + ca*sb + ca*sc + ca*se + 
 ca*sg + ca*sh;
f2 =cb*sa - ca*sb - cc*sb - cd*sb - cf*sb - ch*sb + cb*sc + cb*sd + 
 cb*sf + cb*sh;
f3 =cc*sa + cc*sb - ca*sc - cb*sc - cd*sc - ce*sc - cg*sc + cc*sd + 
 cc*se + cc*sg;
f4 =cd*sb + cd*sc - cb*sd - cc*sd - ce*sd - cf*sd - ch*sd + cd*se + 
 cd*sf + cd*sh;
f5 =ce*sa + ce*sc + ce*sd - ca*se - cc*se - cd*se - cf*se - cg*se + 
 ce*sf + ce*sg;
f6 =cf*sb + cf*sd + cf*se - cb*sf - cd*sf - ce*sf - cg*sf - ch*sf + 
 cf*sg + cf*sh;
f7 =cg*sa + cg*sc + cg*se + cg*sf - ca*sg - cc*sg - ce*sg - cf*sg - 
 ch*sg + cg*sh;
f8 =ch*sa + ch*sb + ch*sd + ch*sf + ch*sg - ca*sh - cb*sh - cd*sh - 
 cf*sh - cg*sh;

f9=sa^2+ca^2-1;
f10=sb^2+cb^2-1;
f11=sc^2+cc^2-1;
f12=sd^2+cd^2-1;
f13=se^2+ce^2-1;
f14=sf^2+cf^2-1;
f15=sg^2+cg^2-1;
f16=sh^2+ch^2-1;



END;
```

Could anyone help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your system of 16 quadratic equations can have up to $2^{16}=65536$ solutions. If the actual number is less than that, then the missing solutions are at (projective) infinity in $\Bbb C^{16}$. The solver will have to follow paths to these roots long enough to make the distinction between very large roots and roots at infinity.

With homotopy continuation the solver starts with a linear system and replaces one equation after the next with equations of the system to solve, using homotopy to proceed from a system with known solutions as start points of the paths to the current unperturbed system. The number of new paths is the previous number of paths times the degree of the new equation.
Typically for the first half of the equations there will be very few paths that diverge, so the number of root paths to follow will increase according to the degrees of the equations. On the other end, most diverging paths will show up when adding the last equations.

The determination if a root path escapes to infinity will also become more difficult the more equations of the original system are involved. This means that multi-precision number types get involved and the number of digits in the working precision can reach rather high numbers.

What you can do, purely from the theoretical side: Check for options that reduce the accuracy of the path-following, that would declare a path at infinity with a higher probability to be wrong.

Make your system more sparse. The first 8 equations follow the pattern `f1 = fac_sa*sa + fac_ca*ca` where `fac_sa, fac_ca` are linear combinations of the other variables. In general it is a bad idea to increase the dimension in a non-linear system, but the increased sparsity in the non-linear equations might add enough structural constraints that the intermediate number of paths gets reduced earlier, so it does not grow as much.